# Are percentages treated as singular or plural in German?

Tags: verb, grammatical-number

For example, if I say "cirka 80% der Deutschen" do I say "ist" or "sind" after?

P.S Please don't tell me to compare it to English because:

1) English and German are *different* languages

2) I don't actually know how it is treated in English (for certain) either

Comment: Even in english you would say ***are*** and not preferably ***be***.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ   "be"??

Comment: @Beta _Well maybe better "About 80% of germans **is a** moron and racist jerks"_ _be_  is used infinitive in my example. I probably should think that over.

Comment: @Beta Fixed my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the percentage is used as a countable numeral such as in the example given we put them in plural:

> 80% der Deutschen **sind** mit ihrem Leben zufrieden.

This is different for the numeral 1 which usually is singular:

> Ein Deutscher ist mit seinem Leben sehr unzufrieden.

Now if we say **one percent** we can see both usages if the result is again a countable quantity (examples from the first page of Google search results):

#### Plural:

> - Nur ein Prozent der Deutschen **sind** bereit, Geldanlagen mit hohem Risiko zu nutzen.
> - Etwa ein Prozent der Deutschen **sind** gegen Erdnüsse allergisch.

#### Singular:

> - Rund ein Prozent der Deutschen **ist** davon betroffen.
> - Etwa ein Prozent der Deutschen **ist** internetabhängig, während es in Asien sieben Prozent sind.

Sometimes this even gets mixed:

> - Ungefähr ein Prozent der Deutschen **sind** pathologische Glücksspieler, ein weiteres Prozent **ist** suchtgefährdet.

Answer (score 2):

> "cirka 80% der Deutschen"

That certainly is a crowd (and not a single german person)

So you clearly have to use plural:

> > cirka 80% der Deutschen **sind** unzufrieden mit **ihrer** Situation.

---

> 2) I don't actually know how it is treated in English (for certain) either

Even in English you would say ***are*** and not ***is (a)***:

> > about 80% of the germans **are** <strike>**is**</strike> unsatisfied with **their** Situation.

Comment: This focusses very much on the one example given. How about a more general answer that addresses the question as if the titl would stand alone?

Comment: This is a correct answer with a wrong argument. A group of Germans is also a crowd and not a single person. Nevertheless, you clearly have to use singular: _die Gruppe von Deutschen **ist** ..._

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Well, that wasn't really in question. If the sentence goes: _"80% der Deutschen sind ... blah ...,  diese Gruppe von Deutschen ist ."_ then maybe Note there's still plural used primarily.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost exactly as it is in [English](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26662/are-percentages-singular-or-plural):

In case the subject we take the percentage of is singular and in the nominative, the verb *may* be singular or plural.

> 80% Energie wird verschwendet.
>
> 80% Energie werden verschwendet.
>
> 80% Energy is wasted. (In English, singular is mandatory)

In case that subject is plural, the verb is plural. The verb must also be plural if the subject is not in nominative.

> 40% Studierende sind Frauen.
>
> 40% der Studierenden sind Frauen.
>
> 40% of the students are women.

Comment: Laut DIN 5008 wird zwischen die Zahl und das Prozentzeichen ein Leerzeichen geschrieben, weil das Symbol ein ganzes Wort abkürzt.

Comment: Würdest auch *Hälfte Energie* schreiben? Mir scheint der Artikel hier unverzichtbar...

Comment: @IQV ... und laut anderen Regelwerken (Duden, z.B.) soll man ein "halbes Leerzeichen" setzen, wenn man kann, oder keins, wenn nicht. Wir sind doch hier nicht in der Industrie ;)

Comment: @guidot Man kann "%" wie eine Maßeinheit betrachten - dann braucht man keinen Artikel (man schreibt auch nicht "ein Dutzend der Eier"). Man kann es auch wie einen "Anteil" betrachten, dann sollte man einen Artikel setzen, da gebe ich dir Recht. Die Beispiele stammen fast wörtlich aus "Duden, gutes und richtiges Deutsch" und sollten daher einigermaßen wasserdicht sein.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

> Das *eine* Buch *ist* spanndend.
>
> Die *achtzig* Bücher *sind* spannend.

Here, it is pretty clear that *ist* is used for a single item and *sind* for many items. The form of the verb *sein* depends on how many items you are talking about.

Now, what are percentages? Well, percentages are used to express proportions, more precisely the number of items per one hundred of similar items. Actually, *percent* is Latin for *von Hundert*. So, the form of *sein* still depends on how many items (of one hundret) you are talking about:

> Das *eine* Buch von hundert Büchern *ist* spannend.
>
> Die *achtzig* Bücher von hundert Büchern *sind* spannend.

or, expressed using the percentage symbol,

> Das 1 % der Bücher *ist* spannend.
>
> Die 80 % der Bücher *sind* spannend.

In summary, we have

> einer (von hundert) ist ⇒ 1 % ist
>
> achtzig (von hundert) sind ⇒ 80 % sind

Comment: What if the 1% refers to 10 books out of 1000?

Comment: @AndrewJames The question "What if ... " does not make sense, because 10 out of 1000 actually does refer to 1%, just as _1a_ out of _100a_ does for any positive-real number _a_. Mathematically speaking, proportions are invariant with respect to the change of unit. Of course, you may express 10 out of 1000 differently, for example, as _"das **sind** 10 Promille"_. But that does not affect the other expression "_das **ist** ein Prozent_".

Comment: So you mean to say that if 1% of the books is 10 books, you can still say "1%  der Buecher ist..."?